# Firefox slow starting on CentOS 7

Tags: firefox, centos7

I am using CentOS 7 in a project. The PC has no internet access, there is a DNS server and web application is used in this CentOS 7 PC. 
When I start firefox, it is starting up too slow. Then everything is ok. When I disable DNS and add hosts, no problem. However I have to use DNS.

I tried to disable DNS prefetching, auto update of search engine etc but I hae still the same problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding hostname to /etc/hosts solved the problem.